# Why radio button is not getting checked by clicking corresponding text is not working in HTML?

Tags: html, label, internet-explorer-10

When user click NO then corresponding radio button should get checked along with direct click on button. Following is snippet from one of my code:

```
<span style="display: inline-block;">
    <label for="kug.bla0">
        <p>
            <input id="kug.bla0" type="radio" value="No" name="kug.bla[0]">
            No  
        </p>
    </label>
</span>
```

Is there any way to do it without modifying HTML at all. Please see fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zp9y75sv/

Is there any small JQuery Snippet which get applied to all 50 questions which have similar kind of answer in Yes, No Format?

**Update**:

The above code is not working in Development environment of client. He is using IE10. Any particular reasons? No errors in JS Console(Firebug).

**Update 2**:
Just to update, if it is related, Pure CSS is being used on out of above span

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">.
```

May be it give any issue?

**Update 3**:
It looks some issue with iframe, in which this exists or some third party?

Comment: But it is not working in real environment. Unable to find reason. The Code is same as given to you. Using IE10

Comment: Don't use `.` in IDs. I think it's legal, but it will cause problems if you try to refer to the ID in CSS selectors.

Comment: And older browsers probably don't support it.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  As Satpal said, your fiddle works.  Are you trying to get rid of the label?  Or what?

Comment: @Barmar, Agree with you on _Don't use . in ID_ However I won't effect as `input` is child of `label` my only concern is "Whether p tag can be child of label"

Comment: @Barmar
But . is already there in code, and i am not authorize to change it

Comment: Please elaborate *Does not work*. Do you get any console errors? Do you have JS disabled?

Comment: @Shaunak D
It shows Nothing. No It is enabled.

Comment: What does Javascript and jQuery have to do with this. It's just plain HTML.

Comment: I tried your fiddle in IE10, it worked for me.

Comment: @Barmar
Now what you suggest to do? As it is not working in environment. I got its access. I opened page in firebug and did changes there and nothing worked. I tried in all latest browsers there but in vein. Could you please suggest some steps to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above snippet was correct and so it is working correctly. After workaround, i found the error is in code explained below:

For those Radio, for which it was not working was because The value of `for` in `<label>` and Value of `id` in `input` are different.

As the `for` attribute specifies which form element a `label` is bound to. We must bound it to `id`; not to `name` or some other value.

Following is snippet demonstrates the same:

```
<label for="kug.bla[1]">
  <p>
  <input  id="kug.bla4" type="radio" value="JA" name="kug.bla[1]" >LabelForBoundByName</input>  
       </p>
</label>
<label for="kug.bla1">
<p>
<input id="kug.bla1" type="radio" value="Yes" name="kug.bla[0]">
    LabelForBoundById</input>  
</p>
</label>
<label for="Independent Label">
  <p>
  <input  id="kug.bla5" type="radio" value="JA" name="kug.bla[5]" >LabelForBoundByNothing</input>  
       </p>
    </label>
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zp9y75sv/2/

Comment: OMG, I know this and I sat here for half an hour trying to figure out why it didn't work lol Thanks you for showing me what I already knew but couldn't remember. long day.!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works corretly. Maybe you can change `<p>` and `<label>` order to have better html support. However if it doesn't work for you probably is a browser issue, try to update.

Works in IE 10/11, latest Chrome and Safari